# Xcode Sidemenu with SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swrevealviewcontroller

I have been trying to implement a slide menu from left using SWRevealViewController. 
I have been following an article [here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) which says that the Reveal view controller should be root/initial view controller. However in my case I want a slide out menu on "Home" which is the 3rd screen in my storyboard.

I have segues defined from 1st scene to Home and 2nd scene to home depending on the conditions.

Questions:

1. Where can I fit in the Reveal view controller?
2. What to do with the "segues" to "Home"?

Comment: I assume those 1st and 2nd scene should be like LOGIN and Registration are they ? then in that case. Set your root-view-controller  as Reveal view controller. and for 1st and 2nd scene, you can present those controller and if you don't want to do that that you can change the root-view-controller  programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

The Root View Controller is The first screen that launches after the app delegate.

> the Reveal view controller should be root/initial view controller.

The statement basically means-
Segue to the Reveal View Controller instead of "Home" for displaying the home page with side menu.The "Home" screen is a subview of the Reveal View Controller.

Just segue from the 2nd screen to the Reveal View controller.

It appears That the Following configuration works.

1. In storyboard set `SWRevealViewController` as Initial View Controller.
2. In appDelegate -

   `self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"1stScreen"];`
3. Instead of segues to Home do-
   `[self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SWRevealViewController"];`

make sure to set the storyboard id of `SWRevealViewController` to "SWRevealViewController".